# Better way to achieve TikZ label offset

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment

In the following diagram,
[image: Graph of a function partitioned into three subintervals]
which is generated by the following Ti*k*Z code,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h] \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,
    % function
    declare function={ f(\x) = pow(\x,4)/16-pow(\x,3)/4+1.1*\x+0.5; },
    % styles
    faint/.style={thin, gray},
    normal/.style={thin, black}]
% axes
\draw [thick, ->] (0, 0) -- (0, 5);
\draw [thick, ->] (0, 0) -- (4.5, 0);
\foreach \x/\xstr/\ystr in {0.6/$a = x_1$\kern 21pt/$f(a) = y_1$, 2.0/$x_2$/$y_2$, 3.3/$x_3$/$y_3$, 3.8/$\kern 19pt x_4 = b$/$f(b) = y_4$} {
    % partitions (x-axis, y-axis)
    \draw [faint] (\x, {f(\x)}) -- (\x, 0) node [normal, below, text height=8pt] {\xstr};
    \draw [faint] (\x, {f(\x)}) -- (0, {f(\x)}) node [normal, left] {\ystr};
    % points
    \fill (\x, {f(\x)}) circle (1pt);
}
% curve
\draw [thick, <->, domain=-0.5:4, samples=50] plot(\x, {f(\x)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I use `\kern` to offset the labels $a = x_1$ and $x_4 = b$ so that the $x$ is always directly under the partition lines on the graph. This seems hacky, and I think there ought to be a better way, like how I can insert an `&` in an `align` environment to make text align to a particular character.

So is there a better way?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also use `\phantom` for that since the amount of shift is not constant hence not worth automating. But instead I would go about with pgfplots.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={f(\x)=pow(0.5*\x,4)-pow(\x,3)/4+1.1*\x+0.5;}]
\begin{axis}[
  axis lines*=middle,
  xtick={0.6,2,3.3,3.8},ytick=data,
  xticklabels={$a=x_1\phantom{a=}$,$x_2$,$x_3$,$\phantom{{}=b}x_4=b$},
  yticklabels={$f(a)=y_1$,$y_2$,$y_3$,$f(b)=y_4$},
  typeset ticklabels with strut]

\addplot[only marks,samples at={0.6,2,3.3,3.8}] {f(x)};
\addplot[thick, <->, domain=-0.2:4, samples=50] {f(x)};
\pgfplotsextra{
  \foreach\x in{0.6,2,3.3,3.8}{
    \draw[thin, gray] (\x,0) |- (0,{f(\x)});
  }
}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! `\phantom` was exactly what I was looking for. (I will probably not use `pgfplots` because the diagram actually has more components, which I removed from the MWE.) For future visitors, note that a small amount of spacing is lost when you use `phantom` unless you include a placeholder, like: `a=x_1\phantom{{}=a}` and `\phantom{b={}}x_4=b`.

Comment: Alternatively, you could write, `$\llap{$x={}$}x_1$`. Or if you load the `mathtools` package, `$\mathllap{x={}}x_1$`.